# derby Data migration using liquibase

Tags: java, derby, liquibase

How to assign two columns to one index in Lquibase datamigration.xml file for Derby DB. I have used following codes which work fine with oracle and MSSQL. but derby is creating two rows with same index name.

```
<createIndex indexName="idx_group_name" tableName="rights" unique="true">
            <column name="name"/>
            <column name="group_name"/>
        </createIndex>
```

Comment: The above code results as follows: oracle:- indexName = idx_group_name; column name = name, group_name. However, Derby does different; it creates two index names; such as: indexName = idx_group_name; column name = name and indexName = idx_group_name; column name = group_name. I would appreciate if you could help to work as in oracle. I need to fix it because in next step of data migration derby is complaining that it has duplicate index name. thanks

Comment: The underlying Derby database can handle a multi-column index (https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj20937.html), so the issue is that for some reason liquibase isn't generating the single multi-column index.

Comment: @BryanPendleton thanks for your inputs. I think there should be some ways to fix it in liquibase. Can anyone give an insight? Thanks

Comment: Can you run the liquibase with ´updateSQL´ to prove it really creates 2 sqls? I don't see anything in the liquibase code that creates two statements on derby (or handles derby different at all while creating indexes). But I also don't oversee the whole code...

Comment: @Jens I am not sure whether it creates 2sqls or not but above code is creating two index names with each column name for Derby but one index name and column names separated by comma for Oracle and MSSQL.

Comment: I understand your problem. But to find the problem you should try the updateSQL and let us know about the result...

Comment: @Jens can you give me example code to run updateSQL because I couldn't figure out how? thanks

Comment: How do you run liquibase right now? Can you paste the command line (if you're using it with the command line?

Comment: using command --migrate; I have DataMigartion.java file where I called Liquibase and dbmigration.xml file(where database table and columns are set up as required to migrate data). This java file is build as jar and is called from batch file as a command.

Comment: Derby DB was complaining while uploading same data from csv file. Issue was resolved by not uploading csv file from dbmigration.xml file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derby DB was complaining while uploading same data from csv file. Issue was resolved by not uploading csv file from dbmigration.xml file. Thanks